# I CANNOT get rid of brackets when trying to print these lists for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

[image]

I have tried most methods but for some reason it just does not want to print without the brackets. Why is that??

Comment: Please don't use images of text, rather use the text directly! Also, why does your function not use the parameter it takes and instead use two objects that are otherwise unclear? Please provide a [mcve]! Also, why did you tag this with `class`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: at the moment, it looks like `list1` is a list of lists.  If this is unexpected, it might point to an error someplace else in your code.

Comment: What is `list1`, where is it defined? What is the problem? What would be the expected output? Your code is unusable in two ways, first it is an image so it cannot be reused to test, and anyway there is not enough context to reproduce your output. Writing good question takes time and care.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `list1` and/or `list2` are lists of lists. Try:

```
for x in list1:
    print(x[0])
for y in list2:
    print(y[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey reffering to the first answer which i really liked, it makes you use indexing which i dont really like in my code writing in python.
The complete solution **without** using any external library or indexing is to use a nested for loop, if it is really a list of lists use the function like so:

```
def printMe(self):
  for list in list1:
     for x in list:
        print(x)
```

and the same for the second list,
I was able to repredouce your work and it worked, i wouldve used also more parsing in the strings but it is your own choice,
Hope it helped :)

Comment: That might be the most reasonable solution. One thing I'd suggest is to avoid naming variables `list`. This overrides python's built-in `list`, which might cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by an extra axis.
Try this:

```
for x in list1[0]:
     print(x)
```

Comment: This would work if the list had 1 element which was a list, so 1xN. But this looks like Nx1, i.e. multiple one-element lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the list without square brackets use the command:
print(*x,sep=" ")